# Holdout on view layer in Blender 2.8 causing white edges around alpha

Tags: transparency

I was wondering if anyone could assist? I am attempting to place an astronaut in a phone booth and render the booth and astronaut as separate render layers.
They are each on their own view layer and in their own collections.The result of my render and node graph below is large white boarder around the astronaut. Any help would be appreciated. My hope is to be able to render the layers separately for colour correction. Motion blur seems to make the white border worse.I have included rendered images and the compositing node setup below. I have set the astronaut to have a holdout on the Phone Booth View layer.[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Does the white border appear only when motion blur is present?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be back and I'm not sure how to remove the white border.

Comment: I am not sure if you need to mask the astronaut from the booth. Do this, render the booth with the astronaut, and then on a second layer render the astronaut by himself like you did before for color correction. This should take care of any alpha issues (also try checking pre-multiply alpha) and it should also take care of motion blur issues. Hope that helps!